# Keep getting error 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, python-2.7

Keep getting this split error, when trying to split up my list Word by Word, line by line.

I got a file which contains links, +20000 links. These links is in a list called "links"

my code so far:

```
import networkx as nx

# Create graph
network_graph = nx.Graph()

path = []
with open('paths_finished.tsv','r') as tsv:
    paths = [line.strip().split('\t') for line in tsv]  
    newPath = paths[16:]


links = []    
for line in newPath:
    links.append(line[3:4])

newList = []

for i in links:
    newList.append(i.split(';'))

print newList
```

The lenght of the links list = 51318.
I want to split up the " ; " in every links in my list.

For example the first link in the file are:

```
['14th_century;15th_century;16th_century;Pacific_Ocean;Atlantic_Ocean;Accra;Africa;Atlantic_slave_trade;African_slave_trade'],
```

Then I want to split it up Word by Word, so I got:

```
['14th_century 15th_century 16th_century Pacific_Ocean Atlantic_Ocean Accra Africa Atlantic_slave_trade African_slave_trade'],
```

Comment: I suspect your indentation for the `for line in newPath` loop is either off, or entirely wrong (you'll only process the last `newPath`).

Comment: So you have a list that contains one element (a very long string) and you want to return a list with the very same string element where `;` is replaced by ' ' (whitespace)? Or you want a list where each word is an element?

Comment: yes, thats what i want ..:)

Comment: `l` is your first list. `x = [l[0].replace(';', ' ')]` (list with one string) |  `y = l[0].split(';')` (list of words)

Comment: Why are you slicing? `links.append(line[3:4])` should just be `links.append(line[3])`.

Comment: ohh i see that links.append(line[3]) also Works.

Answer (score 2):

First thing - as Martijn Pieters said, your indentation is off. Its hard to guess exactly what you mean, please fix it. But:

```
paths = [line.strip().split('\t') for line in tsv]
```

line.split('\t') already returns a list. You put that list into `path` so `path` is a list of lists. You iterate over that list of lists here:

```
for line in newPath:
   links.append(line[3:4])
```

so links will also be a list of lists. And finally:

```
for i in links:
   newList.append(i.split(';'))
```

you try to call `split` for `i` - which is a list. split is a member function of `str` and does not exist for lists - hence your error.

Comment: I'm new to python, so i'm really sorry if i done something wrong :P
So you saying its stupid to use that many lists?

Comment: Hey, Im not saying its stupid. I was just explaining your code. You probably could have just used split() with no delimiters on the whole .tsv file. It would split on `\t` and `\n` so you have one list of strings which im guessing is what you want.